# chrome API override history page examples

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-history

Am trying to override the history page in chrome using an extension. I have set the override page option in manifest.json file and created a new history.html file. The extension is running perfect and the history page showing blank now. I need to list all the history in my new override page history.html page. Is there any way to do this?

Here is my manifest.json file.

```
{


 "name": "Recently visited urls",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Recently visited urls",
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["popup.js"]
  }],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery.js","background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Recently visited urls",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": "clock.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "history",
    "downloads"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
  "chrome_url_overrides": {
    "history": "history.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

If you mean why your customized history page is blank, have you declared `history` permission in your manifest.json?

**Update:**

Since [chrome.history](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history) api can only be accessed through background scripts, we need to do message passing from background scripts to your override history page. However, we can't inject content scripts to chrome://history and after trying many methods, I think using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API) is a workaround to solve this problem.

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Search History",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Your description",
    "chrome_url_overrides": {
        "history": "history.html"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "permissions": [
        "history"
    ]
}
```

history.html (here I just concat all localStorage in a string, you can customize your view here)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="historyText"></p>
    <script src="content.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

background.js (you can configure history items number by setting maxResults to other number)

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function () {
    chrome.history.search({ text: '', maxResults: 10 }, function (data) {
        data.forEach(function(page) {
            localStorage.setItem("Id: " + page.id + ", title: " + page.title, page.url);
        });
    });
});
```

content.js

```
var historyText = "";
for(var key in localStorage) {
    historyText += key + ": " + localStorage.getItem(key) + ", ";
}

document.getElementById("historyText").innerText = historyText;
```

Comment: I have already declared the history permission in manifest.json. Here is my history.html file.
<html>
<head>
 <title>History</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  

 </div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: If possible, could you please edit your question and provide more details about your code, including manifest.json and other related code?

Comment: @vivekk, I have updated implementation code, please have a look and see if it solved your question.

Comment: Okay. This is cool. I have one more doubt. I have synced my phone with chrome browser. So that i can view all my phone search history from my desktop browser.But when i using chrome.history.search function for getting chrome history in my extension, the function return only the desktop browser URL's. Is there any way to get the synced devices search history as well?

Comment: Form [Sync your account settings](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/2914794?hl=en), you can save and sync things like your history, bookmarks, and passwords to your Google Account. That way you'll always have them on any ChromeBbook and in Google Chrome on other devices where you're signed in. So I think you have signed in your account, then you can call chrome.history.search() to get all your browsering history among all devices

Comment: I have synced my devices and did some searches on using mobile. The search history is showing on the chrome://history page. But when i use the chrome.history.search() its returns only the desktop browser URL's. The chrome.history.search()  not taking the other device URL's.

Comment: @vivekk, I have not tested this scenario so I just don't have much info here, maybe you can start another question.

Comment: Okay, Thanks Haibara Ai.